# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever i try to install any package i am getting this error not sure why it is occurring can anyone help?

```
C:\Users\DT250>python -m pip install jupyter
Error processing line 1 of C:\Users\DT250\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vision-1.0.0-py3.11-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<frozen site>", line 186, in addpackage
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 570, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Comment: It looks like part of a namespace package was deleted, or your have a corrupted Python installation. Without more details. it's likely that the best we can suggest is to re-install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error in the `.pth` file.

Try to delete `C:\Users\DT250\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vision-1.0.0-py3.11-nspkg.pth` and reinstall the package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mingjie-MSFT Which package do i need to install ?

Comment: @Nazima The command `pip install jupyter` in your issue.